# Add json content as an element to list python

Tags: python, json

I have JSON content that I need to add to a list as an element to that list. While doing so, 'list.append()' method converts the JSON content to string which I don't want. Hence, how can I add an JSON content as an element to the list such that it is still a JSON?

This is what I was trying:

```
def dump_data():
    for data in prod_data:
        file_name = data['filter'] + '_1.json'
        path = check_file_existance(file_name)  # If file exists, then this method generates a new file name.
        enter_data = list()
        enter_data.append(json.dumps(data))
        print type(enter_data[0])
        with open(path, "ab+") as f:
            # json.dump(data, f)
            f.write("%s\n" % enter_data)
```

Comment: @JohnZwinck: I've added my code.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
    enter_data.append(json.dumps(data))
```

You are converting the JSON to a string by `json.dumps`.  Instead, try this:

```
    enter_data.append(data)
```

A simpler version of your entire loop might be:

```
enter_data = list(prod_data)
```

Comment: Please look at my 'entire' code. I initially posted just a small piece of code to avoid going more deep in my code.

Comment: OK, I looked.  Now what?